# Trouble with Tkinter coordinates and intialization using place()

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label

Very new to tkinter and came across my first major roadbloack.  I have a list of labels that is follows around a parent label.  I have a function that displays all of these labels based off the coordinates of this parent.  Right now the coordinates for the parent label are set at 0,0 no matter where I place it.

Here is the initialization and call of DisplayUnits:

```py
#operations
OperationsChildren = []
templabel1 = Label(MyCanvas, text = "Operations", font=("Arial Bold", 12))
templabel1.place(x = 30, y = 0,)
Operations = CreateSection("Operations", OperationsChildren, None, OperationsList)
Operations.HeaderLabel = ObjectLabel("Operations", templabel1, Operations, MouseObject)
Operations.ChildLabels = DisplayUnits(Operations, MyCanvas, MouseObject)

#medical
MedicalChildren = []
templabel2 = Label(MyCanvas, text = "Medical", font=("Arial Bold", 12))
templabel2.place(x =200, y = 50,)
Medical = CreateSection("Medical", MedicalChildren, None, MedicalList)
Medical.HeaderLabel = ObjectLabel("Medical", templabel2, Medical, MouseObject)
Medical.ChildLabels = DisplayUnits(Medical, MyCanvas, MouseObject)
```

And here is my display function

```py
def DisplayUnits(Section, Frame, DebugLabel):
    #remove labels inside of sections current label list
    for x in Section.ChildLabels:
        x.label.destroy()
    #initialize label list that will be populated by the new labels
    LabelList = []
    #get initial x and y coordinates
    startX = Section.HeaderLabel.label.winfo_x()
    startY = Section.HeaderLabel.label.winfo_y()
    print("start values are " + str(startX) + ", " + str(startY))
    #set an iterator which will determine how far apart each label is spaced
    SpaceIterator = startY + 20
    for index, x in enumerate(Section.SecUnitList): #indexing not needed or used yet
        tempName = x.name
        tempLabel = Label(Frame, text = tempName, font=("Arial Bold", 12))
        #set the location equal to the startx and the iterator which is the advancing Y value
        tempLabel.place(x=startX,y=SpaceIterator)
        #create ObjectLabel class using templabel,
        UnitLabel = ObjectLabel(tempName, tempLabel, None, DebugLabel)
        
        
        LabelList.append(UnitLabel)
        print("Display Iterator is at " + str(SpaceIterator)  + " for the unit "+ tempName)
        SpaceIterator = SpaceIterator+20 #create label one row below last row
        
    return LabelList
```

this is what I am seeing
[image: this is what I am seeing]

this is what I want and am expecting to happen
[image: this is what I want]

changing to pack and grid based for the parent label.  Adding debugs that show the header label location is considered to be at 0,0 even though it is not.  I think it might have to do with local vs global positioning but don't know where to even start on checking that.

Comment: Your question as written is very hard to read. While we do appreciate information and images that help to understand your problem, it is rather unlikely that someone is willing to work this posting through. Try to focus on a [mre], briefly state your questions and post a single image that contains both, what you want and what you get instead next to each other. More input of how you should [edit] your question can be found in the [help] of [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't normally recommend using `place`, you can achieve what you want by `place`'s ability to do relative placement. Since we can't reproduce your problem from the code snippets you've presented, here's a simple example that illustrates the concept.

The key is using the `in_` parameter which defines what the relative coordinates are relative to, and the `relx` (relative x) and `rely` (relative y) parameters. It also sets `bordermode` to "outside", which means that the relative coordinates are relative to the widget edges rather than the interior portions of the widget.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background="blue")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

medical_label = tk.Label(canvas, text="Medical")
r2_label = tk.Label(canvas, text="R2")
r3_label = tk.Label(canvas, text="R3")

medical_label.place(x=100, y=100)
r2_label.place(in_=medical_label, relx=0.0, rely=1.0, bordermode="outside")
r3_label.place(in_=r2_label, relx=0.0, rely=1.0, bordermode="outside")
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you this actually did solve my issue!  What would you recommend instead of place()?  For my aims I want the user to be able to drag wherever they want so it seemed the most appropriate at the time.

Comment: @Wowbagger: if you're wanting users to move things around, `place` is the appropriate tool.